# Display a validation error message at drop down level

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to display a validation error message at drop down level.
if i try to select a option in drop down when check box = checked it should show validation error message. This is the code I have tried
please help me what should i add in java script,i tried by disabling drop down but i need error message besides drop down when i try to select options in drop down ?

```html
       <html><head>
<script>

function validate()
{
var e1 = document.getElementById("chkdd1");
   if(e1.checked == "")
   {
      //alert("Please enable check box"); 
      document.getElementById("chkdd1").textContent="xbn"
      //document.getElementById("chkdd1").style.color="Red";
      document.getElementById("chkdd1").focus(); 

      return false;
   }else{
   return true;
   }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="checkbox" id="chkdd1" />
<select id="DDL1" onchange="validate(this)">
    <option >yes</option>
    <option >no</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why you have multiple dropdowns?

Comment: @LuísRamalho he is not saying on disabled element anywhere in question.

Comment: @jsduniya, you're right! Completely missed the point the question :)

Comment: @Mahesh 
bro i have 7 different drop downs so i used like this for demonstration

Answer (score 1):

Add Class to all select element option "class=sel" and trigger event on change.

```js
function enabledd1(chkdd1){
    var dd1=document.getElementById("DDL1");
    var dd2=document.getElementById("DDL2");
    var dd3=document.getElementById("DDL3");
    var dd4=document.getElementById("DDL4");
    var dd5=document.getElementById("DDL5");
    var dd6=document.getElementById("DDL6");
    var dd7=document.getElementById("DDL7");

    dd1.disabled=chkdd1.checked ? false : true;
    dd2.disabled=chkdd1.checked ? false : true;
    dd3.disabled=chkdd1.checked ? false : true;
    dd4.disabled=chkdd1.checked ? false : true;
    dd5.disabled=chkdd1.checked ? false : true;
    dd6.disabled=chkdd1.checked ? false : true;
    dd7.disabled=chkdd1.checked ? false : true;


        if(!dd1.disabled && !dd2.disabled && !dd3.disabled && !dd4.disabled && !dd5.disabled && !dd6.disabled && !dd7.disabled){
        dd1.focus();
        dd2.focus();
        dd3.focus();
        dd4.focus();
        dd5.focus();
        dd6.focus();
        dd7.focus();
        }
    }
var allSel = document.querySelectorAll('.sel');
allSel.forEach(function(el){
el.addEventListener('change', function(){
   alert('add error message')
   // Here you can set error message and show it wherevver you want
      
   
})
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="checkbox" id="chkdd1" onclick="enabledd1(this)" required="" />
<select class="sel" id="DDL1" disabled="disabled">
    <option value="" selected="">yes</option>
    <option>no</option>
</select>

<select class="sel" class="sel" id="DDL2" disabled="disabled">
    <option value="" selected="">yes</option>
    <option>no</option>
</select>
<select class="sel" id="DDL3" disabled="disabled">
    <option value="" selected="">yes</option>
    <option>no</option>
</select>
<select class="sel" id="DDL4" disabled="disabled">
    <option value="" selected="">yes</option>
    <option>no</option>
</select>
<select class="sel" id="DDL5" disabled="disabled">
    <option value="" selected="">yes</option>
    <option>no</option>
</select>
<select class="sel" id="DDL6" disabled="disabled">
    <option value="" selected="">yes</option>
    <option>no</option>
</select>
<select class="sel" id="DDL7" disabled="disabled">
    <option value="" selected="">yes</option>
    <option>no</option>
</select>

</body></html>
</html>
```